# How can I pay estimated taxes when I'm no longer filing jointly?

Tags: united-states, irs, estimated-taxes

Suppose that I am married and have been filing taxes jointly with my spouse for years, with my spouse as the primary taxpayer. For the upcoming tax year (here, tax year 2023, since at the time of writing it is April 2023), we plan to file separately. I need to pay estimated taxes for Q1 income, which normally I would do through the [IRS Direct Pay portal](https://directpay.irs.gov/directpay/payment?execution=e1s1).

However, this form is clear that I should use my spouse's information to verify identity for the purposes of submitting the estimated tax payment. There's no place for me to enter my own name, or indicate that these payments should be credited to the secondary taxpayer (me). How can I pay this estimated tax and ensure that it's credited to my balance, not my spouse's?

I found this article—[Assignment of Estimated Tax Payments in a Divorce](https://www.thetaxadviser.com/issues/2015/oct/assignment-of-estimated-tax-payments-in-a-divorce.html)—but it doesn't really have an answer, and also we're not divorced.

Comment: @littleadv - The form asks for a previous return to verify identity, which for the OP is an MFJ return with the spouse's SSN as primary.  It then goes to the bank account information for the debit.  I understand why he is asking the question.

Answer (score 3):

You should create an IRS account and use it to pay rather than going through the Direct Pay portal.  This will ensure that the payments are connected to your taxpayer ID rather than to the MFJ taxpayer ID.